# EasyBCD won't boot Debian after upgrade

Tags: boot, debian, grub2, easybcd

I have a desktop that dual-boots Debian and Windows 7.  When I turn it on, it uses the Windows bootloader, as configured by EasyBCD.  If I select Debian, it then chainloads(?) GRUB, which lets me select and boot a Linux kernel.

This morning, I upgraded from wheezy to jessie on the Debian side*, and when I rebooted and selected Debian, it put me into a GRUB4DOS command line.  I can find the right hard drive, and by `cat`ing my grub config and using the `kernel`, `initrd`, and `boot` commands, I've managed to boot into Debian.

I then ran `update-grub`, which did some stuff and looked like it might have plausibly fixed the issue.  When I rebooted, though, I got set right back into that GRUB4DOS command line.  I booted from there again, but I'd rather not have to do this every time.

Does anyone know what the issue is or how I can fix it?

I think my EasyBCD version is 2.X, but I'm not sure what X is.  I can find out if necessary, but that involves booting back into Windows, which means doing the GRUB4DOS dance to get back into Debian.

*I also installed task-kde-desktop, which I think is not relevant, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't think it'll be relayed to EasyBCD because you at least get to GRUB - albeit the GRUB rescue mode. You may need to look at your `menu.lst` File manually as it may be missing your Debian settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what caused the problem, but **(a)** upgrading EasyBCD from 2.1.2 to 2.2 and **(b)** adding a boot entry that explicitly specified the disk I wanted to boot from fixed my problem.